# Convergence of $\max$ and tail events

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(X_n)_n$ be a sequence of real random, and consider the tail $\sigma$-algebra generated by $(X_n)_n: \mathcal{F}=\bigcap\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\sigma\left(\bigcup_\limits{k \geq n}\sigma(X_k)\right).$
Prove or disprove the following statement:

$1) \left\{w;\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} X_k(w) \text{ converges }\right\} \in \mathcal{F},$

$2)\left\{w;\dfrac{\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} X_k(w)}{n} \text{ converges }\right\}\in \mathcal{F}.$

So, since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, and taking $r \in \mathbb{N},$ $$\left\{w;\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} X_k(w) \text{ converges }\right\}=\bigcap_{p \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{n_0 \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcap_{n \geq n_0}\bigcap_{q \in \mathbb{N}}\left\{w;|\max_{1 \leq k \leq n+r+q} X_k(w)-\max_{1\leq k \leq n+r}X_k(w)|\leq\frac{1}{p}\right\}$$
$$=\bigcap_{p \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{n_0 \in \mathbb{N}}\bigcap_{n \geq n_0}\bigcap_{q \in \mathbb{N}}\left\{w;\max(\max_{n+r+1 \leq k \leq n+r+q} X_k(w)-\max_{1\leq k \leq n+r}X_k(w),0)\leq\frac{1}{p}\right\}$$

Any ideas how to continue?

Comment: Sorry, my first comment had an incorrect idea in mind. Instead, I observe that for part 1, the max is a nondecreasing function of n and converges if and only if that function does not go to infinity.

Comment: I tried to use the completeness of $\mathbb{R},$ don't know if it can work, but since the sequence is increasing $\max_{k}X_k$ converges if and only if $\sup_{k>r}X_k<+\infty$ which is a tail event.